# Getting text from an url with AsyncTask. Code is not working for some reason

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get text from urls and display them as strings. Urls end with .txt as in www.gains.com/more.txt These text are long and they have a maximum size of 1MB. I am trying to get them it with AsyncTask. The problem is that the code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I have no idea why.

Here is the AsyncTask code.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    // username, password, message, mobile
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // constants
        int timeoutSocket = 15000;        //Is this enough for 1MB files?
        int timeoutConnection = 15000;

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0]);

        try {
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
                return null;
            }

            line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }

            line = total.toString();

            return line;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        story.add(result);   //story is the array which I use to display the downloaded text
    }
}
```

And here is how i call it. I call it inside a method which is not OnCreate and I even do it inside a new thread to avoid the NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new RequestTask().doInBackground("www.gains.com/more.txt");
            new RequestTask().onPostExecute(line);
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

it's not the right way to call asynctask. You can t call doinbackground direclty, neither postexecute.
What you have to do is just to write :

```
RequestTask MyAsynchTask = new RequestTask().
MyAsynchTask.execute("www.gains.com/more.txt");
```

it s the public execute method who will call all the method for you : preexecute, doinbackground and postexecute.

and you won t have ANR problem ( Application Not Responding ) with this solution.

tell me if it's ok for you

you said : sometimes it works sometimes no ? when you write :

```
requestTask().doInBackground("www.gains.com/more.txt");
        new RequestTask().onPostExecute(line);
```

java can t' know in postexecute if doinbackground is finished or not ! so sometimes you will have your result, and sometimes no, it depends of how much time java takes to work in the doinbackgroundmethod.

the only way to implement Asynchtask is to do as i write above. And if you havent the data you wish to have in the result it because of something else.

IT CAN RUN JUST ONCE :  if you want to run it again you have to create antother instance of RequestTask

Comment: Thanks but nothing has changed unfortunately. I still cant see the text.

Comment: I did what you say. This is whats going on. First it worked. I got the text. But when I ran the application again this time there were no text. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: Asynchtask can go just once. If you want to execute it again you have to create another instance ( see above )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following code :

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new RequestTask().doInBackground("www.gains.com/more.txt");
        new RequestTask().onPostExecute(line);
    }
}.start();
```

Use just :

```
new RequestTask().execute("www.gains.com/more.txt");
```

Comment: That's because this answer is incorrect. As @StephaneK said, you do not directly call doInBackground.

Comment: sorry....i didn't see the do in background...change to execute, it will work... The reason for that to not work is android will not allow network operations in UI thread. So while calling the execute method, it will call the do in background in a seperate thread and will give you back the result in onPostExecute(that is in UI thread)